# angularjs - uirouter nested view animation - first $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angularJS 1.6.6 and uirouter 1.0.11. I am in HTML5 mode

I have nested states :

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'home',
  url: 'home/',
  component: 'home',
})

$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'inscription',
  url: 'inscription/',
  component: 'inscription',
})

$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'home.profile',
  url: 'home/profile',
  component: 'profile',
})

$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'home.account',
  url: 'home/account',
  component: 'account',
})
```

Here is my html for body :

```
<ui-view class="body-block-animation"/>
```

And here is my html for home :

```
<div class="home">
  <ui-view class="home-page-animation"/>
</div>
```

I have some css that creates a different animation for each level of route, here is one of them as an example :

```
.home-page-animation {

  &.ng-enter, &.ng-leave {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
  }

  &.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }

}
```

I land on www.example.com/home/profile

Then i move accross pages doing :

```
$state.go('home.profile')
```

And i encounter a graphical bug :

- The landing goes well
- When my first move (using state.go) is from 'home.profile' to 'home.account' the animation is applied on the parent ui-view ('body-block-animation' in body) instead of the current ui-view ('home-page-animation' in home).
- Any further move (using state.go) behaves as expected and only animates the sub-view that changed.

> I have the impression that the first landing through the url does not anchor the parent view the same way as state.go does.
>   Hence the first state.go will not detect that the first ui-view is already the right one and move it anyway.

What is really going on ? How can i patch it ?